# How to update many rows with Where clause

Tags: mysql, dbforge

I have table with rows below:

```
id |  s1  |  s2  |  s3  |  s4  |  s5  |
---------------------------------------
1  |  6   |  2   | null | null | null |
---------------------------------------
2  |  8   |  1   | null | null | null |
```

I have already this values, and I want to add data to cells where **null**

My query is:

```
UPDATE table1
SET s3 = "some_s3" WHERE id = 1
SET s4 = "some_s4" WHERE id = 1
SET s5 = "some_s5" WHERE id = 1
SET s3 = "some_s3" WHERE id = 2
SET s4 = "some_s4" WHERE id = 2
SET s5 = "some_s5" WHERE id = 2
```

Something like this. But i need to update thousand rows.

Comment: If you have to update rows, you have to use update statement

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 UPDATE table1
SET s3 = "some_s3" WHERE s3 is null
 UPDATE table1
SET s4 = "some_s4" WHERE s4 is null
 UPDATE table1
SET s5 = "some_s5" WHERE s5 is null
```

Comment: And write it in 1000 rows?

Comment: @ШыназАлиш Why 1000 rows? You need to update different values for every row? Your question is very unclear

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest way is to write a PHP script if you want to update large amounts of data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but alse I want to learn how to make it in mysql.

Comment: Since MySQL is not a programming language so unfortunately there is no shortcut. You may have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1 SET s3='some_value1',s4='some_value2',s5='some_value3'

WHERE s3 is null and s4 is null and s5 is null
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @MD: My post is supposed to be an answer. I have not asked for any further clarification from the author of the question.